# Unindexed remote maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

```
14:59:30 Unindexed remote maven repositories found. Disable...
The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button (show balloon)
as the picture above shows
```

Could anyone help me with my question?